# How to prevent concurrent futures library from looping over previously iterated items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I have a list (`lst1`) of numerical IDs (roughly 300K IDs) that I am passing into a API, and appending api results into another list (`lst`), like so:

```
lst = []
lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(len(lst1))
counter = 0
for i in lst1:
    url = 'url.com/Id={}'.format(i)
    while True:
        try:
            xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
            counter = counter+ 1
            print(counter)
            #print(xml_data1)
            break
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(e)
    lst.append(xml_data1)
```

When I apply the future.concurrent library the code keeps looping over the same IDs. I can tell this because the counter number keeps repeating, how do I prevent this?

Code to how I am applying the futures.concurrent library:

```
def get_data(xml):
    print(len(lst1))
    #counter = 0
    for i in lst1:
        url = 'url.com/Id={}'.format(i)
        while True:
            try:
                xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
                counter = counter+ 1
                print(counter)
                #print(xml_data1)
                break
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print(e)
        lst.append(xml_data1)

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:  
    df_list = executor.map(get_data, lst1)
```

edit:

```
def get_data(xml):
    #counter = 0
    for i in lst1:
        url = 'url.com/Id={}'.format(i)
        while True:
            try:
                xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
                counter = next(counter_object)
                print(counter)
                #print(xml_data1)
                break
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print(e)
        lst.append(xml_data1)
    return lst
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:  
    lst = executor.map(get_data, lst1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integers are immutable. So you could make your counter global using

```
global counter
```

you could also define a global `counter` object (not integer) using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

This is my preferred method, because it avoids the use of `global` on an immutable object like integer, which always leads to mistakes and misunderstandings.

```
import itertools
counter_object = itertools.count()  # default: starts at 0
```

now:

```
counter = counter+ 1
```

becomes:

```
counter = next(counter_object)
```

And the values won't be the same between worker threads.

This relies on the fact that CPython has a global interpreter lock which makes the operation safe. If you're not using CPython, you have to use threading lock mechanisms to protect the object from concurrent modifications.

the other issue is that `get_data` should not return a list but an item. Let `executor.map` create the list (and your loop is useless/harmful since it multiplies the number of computations)

so to sum it up:

```
def get_data(xml):
    url = 'url.com/Id={}'.format(xml)
    while True:
        try:
            xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
            counter = next(counter_object)
            print(counter)
            break
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(e)
    return xml_data1
```

finally, `executor.map` is made to be iterated upon. To create a list, you have to *force* iteration on it:

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:  
    df_list = list(executor.map(get_data, lst1))
```

Comment: so this definitely fixes the counter issue, but the last line where I have it set to `df_list` is not working. When i change `df_list` to `lst`, the concurrent.futures library stops at the right number of records, if not it keeps running. In either case nothing gets appended into `lst`. Do you know what maybe causing this?

Comment: oh, your `get_data` function should return something: `lst.append(xml_data1)` should be replaced by `return xml_data1`: no side effect, just let `execute` run. Tell me if it works, I overlooked that part trying to fix the counter issue

Comment: If I remove the `lst.append(xml_data1)`  and replace with `return xml_data1`, nothing is getting appended to anywhere even when I have the `df_list` set to `lst`. How should I handle the appending?

Comment: the `xml_data1` is where the results I want are. But how should I handle appending into list?

Comment: I made an edit, with exactly how I have the code. If I dont set last line to `lst` the process keeps running, regardless nothing is getting appended

Comment: sorry, again the mistake was bigger than I thought. get_data should compute _one_ occurrence, or you'll retrieve the list in _each_worker

Comment: I am not following, but another issue not sure if it is related but the iterator `i` is truncating some digits of the IDs in the lsit

Comment: I mean that you aren't using `xml` parameter in your `get_data`. Check the documentation of `executor.map`: the list is created by executor, not by you. You have to think _parallel_ processing. Drop the list let executor build it for you from parallel runs of `get_data` function

Comment: so your edit seems to be working fine, but executor is not building the list into the variable, I can not find it. plus for some reason digits are being truncated on the `iterator`. Would you know why?

Comment: oh you probably have to force iteration: `df_list = list(executor.map(get_data, lst1))` else nothing runs

Comment: Bingo! that works with creating the variable to hold the data, now to figure out why the iterator is cutting off digits on my list of IDs

Comment: per chance are your iterators floats?? I'm glad I could help!!

Comment: they are floats thats probably why.

Comment: use integers instead. Integers have no limit in range. using floats for ids is a _very_ bad idea.

Comment: got it, however python is adding the `.0` at the end.